# How to change the audio session category in iOS on React Native?

Tags: javascript, ios, audio, react-native

Using react native, I understand that in order to enable background audio playback (mainly for react-native video) I should change the audio session as detailed [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1668/_index.html) in the apple development docs.

With that said, I'm a little bit confused about where exactly to do this. Considering that React is javascript, where should one place the Objective-C code in React Native application?

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: @hugger You'll need to do this in native Swift or Objective C code either by writing a Native Module or by adding to your AppDelegate

Comment: @wellthatssomething Isn't the audio session available under NativeModules.RNAudioSession?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering this old question of mine as I see it has a non-zero number of views...

In order to do this in a React Native application, you will indeed need to write either a Native Module using Swift or Objective C code.

You can read more about native modules in the documentation here: 
https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-ios

This will allow you to access Apple APIs (like the audio session) and call them from your Javascript code.

There may also be third party libraries (node modules) that have written this code already, that you may be able to take advantage of.